# image from DRF not loading in react js

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

My react js app just won't load any image from my DRF.
I am suffering quite a while to fix this, but I just can't find a solution.

In my react app, I am fetching data from `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20'` (mapping the results to "<img.." etc.) and the fetched images are loaded with `<img src="https://...." alt='image'>` and they are displayed immediately.
But when I fetch my DRF api, I get a timeout.

`<img className='user-avatar-settings' src={ this.state.photo} alt='user-avatar' />`
where `this.state.photo` is `https://127.0.0.1:8001/media/user_avatar/user_3.jpg`

Chrome is saying:`127.0.0.1:8001/media/user_avatar/user_3.jpg:1 GET https://127.0.0.1:8001/media/user_avatar/user_3.jpg net::ERR_TIMED_OUT` after a little while.

*) The first url isn't correct, the second one is.
*) When clicking the correct url, the image is not loaded (the click redirects to a new Chrome tab, so I am outside of the app).
*) I first need to quit and restart the Django server, afterwards the image is loaded immediately in the Chrome tab - but not inside my react app.
**Even a GET Request with the image url is running into that timeout.**
Here is an example:

```
componentDidMount() {

    fetch(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userpic/${localStorage.getItem('id')}/`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          //response.data from django view "userpic" returns relative path to /media, so the rest of the path needs to be added
          this.setState({ photo: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000' + response.data })
        } else { alert('NOT LOADED') }
      })

    if (this.state.errors && (this.mapErrors() !== undefined)) {
      // Maps errors to text for UI
      return <ul>{this.mapErrors()}</ul>
    }
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      //A loading screen
      return <Splash />
    }

  }

  render() {
       ....

       <img className='user-avatar-settings' src={this.state.photo} alt='user-avatar' />
```

Here is the django view that is called via the url ".../userpic/userid/"

```
class UserUploadImage(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsLoggedInUser, )
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, ]

    serializer_class = AvatarSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
        serializer = AvatarSerializer(user, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And it's not up to that one specific image. None image from backend /media/ folder is showing up in react js - only that one little "placeholder" image from browser (a mini image).

Does this maybe sound familiar to somebody? Does anybody has a clue what could go wrong?

As far as I could research, the backend is fine:

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#location where django collect all static files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')# location where you will store your static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'corsheaders',
    'sslserver',
    'posts',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]
SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static, serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('api/', include('posts.api.urls')),
] 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And as I have already described, the image is saved @backend and callable, but not inside the react js app.

Is there maybe a way of webpack-config workarounds?
Please drop any solution you can imagine..! I will try anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed for firefox: I have deleted the fetch from ComponentDidMount and wrote a new func that is called inside ComponentDidMount with correct async behaviour as follows:

```
//Replace relative path with absolute path
async function setAvatarPath(props) {

  if (props.avatar === "/media/default_m.jpg") {
    try {
      // <img src={window.location.origin + ...
      const response = await fetch("https://127.0.0.1:8000/media/default_m.jpg", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
        },
      }).then(res => userpic = res.url)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  } else {
    try {
      var userid = localStorage.getItem('id')
      const response = await fetch("https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userpic/" + userid + "/", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
        },
      }).then(res => userpic = res.data.avatar)
      console.log(userpic)
    } catch (error) {
      userpic = "https://127.0.0.1:8000/media/default_m.jpg";
    }

  }
}
```

@iserranoe provided the correct [syntax: medium.com/@matt.readout/…](https://medium.com/@matt.readout/using-javascripts-async-await-syntax-to-fetch-data-in-a-react-app-878b930cdc6f)
I have also changed the state variable "photo" to a `var userpic` to avoid the realoading of the whole render method..

**These changes did not affect the behaviour in chrome** - Version 87.0.4280.14 - (request is still timed out and image is not displayed).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

In settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), #Your bundle.js path
    ]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Use DEBUG = True when developing and DEBUG = False in production. In the latter, you should do python manage.py collectstatic

In ursl.py:

```
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I've followed your suggestions and changed settings.py and urls.py as you described above.
python manage.py collectstatic showed, that the directory "static" was missing. So I've created one manually. The command did not output any errors afterwords. 
Nothing else changed through your suggestions... unfortunately, still no image is displayed (still .... net::ERR_TIMED_OUT).

Comment: I see you are using `https://127.0.0.1:8001/media/user_avatar/user_3.jpg`. Are you sure it is https instead of http and the port is 8001? When developing I usually use `http://localhost:8000/`...
And, just in case... is the server workin ok? I mean, can you access the admin site for example or other drf apis?

Comment: Yes I have https in development because I wanted to practice how to integrate certificates for prod. later. Are there known issues with SSL and get requests? I can access every view" or serializer via the browser- so yes I cann access admin page, auth pages etc. **BUT** I need to restart the server!! Every time the react app requests the drf, I need to restart to access via browser and vice versa. So e.g. once I have logged in as admin via browser, the requests from the react app do not reach the server anymore..

Comment: **Adding info:** I have already startet a new django backend with http only, but since the images are not loaded with that new backend neither, I'm suffering even more..

Comment: There should not be any issues with SSL request if the certificates are correct. I was asking in case you were consulting https but the server was in http, which is not the case as you said. 
Can you show the code in Django for the DRF api and the code in React for getting the url?

Comment: I have added the code snippets you asked for (react componentDidMount() and django view for the userpic). The view is always returning the correct image path (relative, starting with "/media/") and calling the whole path returns the image in the browser!
Django returns `[16/Dec/2020 11:15:43] "GET /api/userpic/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 33` to the GET request from react. But still only a mini-image placeholder from browser is displayed..

Comment: This is really wierd, if `this.state.photo` contains the url address correctly and the browser is showing the image... If you right-clic on the mini-image placeholder, and open the image route, is it correct? If this.state.photo was undefined it could have to do with `fetching().then` not waiting correctly. If that is the problem, `async - await` may work better, for example: https://medium.com/@matt.readout/using-javascripts-async-await-syntax-to-fetch-data-in-a-react-app-878b930cdc6f

Comment: I have also tried the async ComponentDidMount but id did not change a thing. It is really frustrating..

Comment: - Correction: Something changed indeed: I am now getting errors from react/babel; uncaught exeptions telling me something is wrong with the proxy.. And I am getting into timeouts even when using async function. The image is loaded in the browser (I can see the "preview" in chrome dev extension) but the image is still displayed as a "mini-preview-image". I think I might have some issues with the react js proxy cors/proxy stuff. I am not using node.js (no such file) - I am just using react js and django. Do I miss something here?

Comment: you have guessed that the async behaviour may not work correctly: I have now set the header with cors-allow-orogin * and content-type image/jpg and **now it works on firefox** - at least so much :). Chrome is waiting and waiting - as it has behaved ever since- and then says "timed out" , while firefox is fully loaded after 5 sec... Wtf :o